# Use Travis CI to build CI/CD pipeline

Tags: angular, spring-boot, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm new to CI/CD and Travis CI, and want to build a CI/CD pipeline for one of my project. The frontend is Angular and the backend is Spring Boot. After I add .travis.yml file to my git repository, Travis CI complains "Could not parse" error in requests panel. I also tried to manually trigger build but it didn't work. Below is structure of my project and the .travis.yml file. Cloud you plz help me to solve this problem?

[image: Project Structure]

```
---
matrix:
  include:

    - language: node_js
      node_js:
        - "10"
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      before_script:
        - cd frontend
        - npm install -g @angular/cli
      script:
        - ng build --prod --base-href https://github.com/TJZhou/pigeon-calendar-springboot/tree/master/frontend/

    - language: java
      dist: trusty
      before_script:
        - cd backend
      script:
        - mvn package
```

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli -> shouldn’t this simply be npm install ?

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks. "npm install" should be better. But the problem is not here.